# Issues with HDF5 file read in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, hdf5

I am trying to read the hdf5 file in visual studio 2017 using c++ language. I already included the header file to the project. They give no error.

```
#include "hdf5.h"
#include "H5Cpp.h"
```

I also set the hdf5 file name to read which also does not give any error.

```
const H5std_string    FILE_NAME(strFile);      //string strFile = "file.h5"
```

But when I add the below line it gives an error -

```
H5File                file(FILE_NAME, H5F_ACC_RDONLY);
```

The debugger shows the below error -

[image]

This is the configuration I use - 
**Operating System: Windows 10**
**Visual Studio - 2017**
**hdf - 1.12.0-Std-win10_64-vs14**

Is there any way to solve the issues or any other way to read the hdf5 file???

[Note: CCalibrationRecovery is my file name and OnBnClickedButton16 is the button event handler.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HDF5 1.12.0 version and follow this link. That will give no issues to use it with visual studio 2015, 2017, and 2019.
[link](https://www.programmersought.com/article/2813194707/)